# How do i create and capture custom fields in ARP message using scapy?

Tags: python, networking, scapy, arp

i am trying to add a custom message to an arp message named is_good_packet. for this purpose i am using scapy. however, when i try to catch it using a sniffer, there are no results with ARPGood. Is there maybe another way to add a custom message to an arp packet?

this is my custom arp packet:

```
class ARPGood(Packet):
    name = "ARPGood"
    fields_desc = [
        ShortEnumField("hwtype", 1, {1: "Ethernet"}),
        ShortEnumField("ptype", 0x0800, {0x0800: "IPv4"}),
        ByteField("hwlen", 6),
        ByteField("plen", 4),
        ShortEnumField("op", 1, {1: "who-has", 2: "is-at"}),
        MACField("hwsrc", "00:00:00:00:00:00"),
        IPField("psrc", "0.0.0.0"),
        MACField("hwdst", "00:00:00:00:00:00"),
        IPField("pdst", "0.0.0.0"),
        BitField("is_good_packet", 0, 1)
    ]
```

and this is my scapy sniffer

```
import scapy.all as sp
from ARPSENDER import ARPGood

def sniff(interface):
    sp.sniff(iface=interface, filter="inbound or outbound", store=False, prn=process_packet)

def process_packet(packet):
    print(packet.summary(), packet.show())
    if packet.haslayer(ARPGood):
        print(f"\n\n\n FOUND IT {packet.is_good_packet} \n\n\n")
sniff("eth0")
```

I tried creating my own class, i thought that the sniffer will catch the packet however it returns no results

Comment: There is no place in an ARP packet for a message. See _[RFC 826, An Ethernet Address Resolution Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826.html)_ that defines ARP and the ARP packet.